# Using VBA to highlight rows that are false in If condition

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to VBA this is my first time. I am using UiPath. I am using an invoke VBA activity in there to highlight certain rows of the Excel if a column is false which requires VBA source code. However, I am not sure how to code nor how to open VBA file. Correct me if I am wrong.

1) I am using Visual Studio to code

2) After through other forum, here is the code that I got:
I am using conditional formatting

```
Sub ConditionalFormat_HighlightRow()
' This routine will highlight the row that contains the word TRUE in the range

' Here it selects the range:
    Range("A1:C10").Select

' Here it defines the formula for the conditional formatting
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=TRUE" 
        "=SEARCH(""Yes""; $C1)=1"

' Here it sets the condition as the highest priority
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

' Here it applies the conditional formatting; You can change the color here.
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense -- why not just use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) instead of VBA?

Comment: If you enter "highlight rows that have condition" on Google, you will get plenty of results to do what you need. And their explanations will probably be better that what we could write here. As Ashleedawg wrote, there is probably no need for VBA for this

Comment: You don't need Visual Studio to code - from within Excel press `Alt+F11` to open the VBEditor.  Your code needs to be added in the correct place there.  I'm not sure what you mean by _which idk can or anot_ though.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to automate the highlighting part. The only option i can do that is to use invoke vba activity.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Oh i see

Comment: You're probably getting that on the second line `A1:E5`. That line's part of the comment above - either add an `'` at the start of the line, delete it or move it to the previous line.  The code you've posted is just adding conditional formatting as @ashleedawg suggest - it changes the colour of columns A:C in the range A1:C10 if column C starts with the word _Yes_ (if the Search returns position 1).

Comment: Change the arguments on your `FormatCoditions.Add` line to `Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=TRUE"` for your purpose.  You might as well do it manually though using `Conditional Formatting` on the `Home` ribbon.

Comment: The whole line should be `Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=TRUE"`.  You can't just add the code I gave you into the middle of your line of code.  You need to add them as arguments to the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add) method of the [FormatConditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.FormatConditions) object. _It really would be easier to do it manually though._

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I tried like u suggested, I am still getting a syntax error

Comment: Ok, if you see an underscore character at the end of a line - `_` it means the next line is a continuation of the current line.  You still have `"=SEARCH(""Yes""; $C1)=1"` on the next line which needs removing.  Again, by following the link in the first comment here you could do this manually much faster.  Why does it need to happen in VBA?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Hi, from what I know 'You use VBA to create a formula-based conditional formatting program" Correct me if I am wrong. So I don't understand when you guys ask me to use Conditional Formatting instead of VBA.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook But if i remove "=SEARCH(""Yes""; $C1)=1" line. It works but does nothing because that's the line that defines the formula. However, Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=SEARCH(""Yes""; $C1)=1"                                                              however, this line still gives me some error

Comment: I need to use VBA as I am trying to automate this highlighting in the excel.  Conditional formatting I got to do manually which cannot be automated. Thus, i need to do in vba

Comment: The VBA code written above automates the manual addition of conditional formatting.  Your code always selects the cells `A1:C10` on the active sheet for formatting and doesn't create a new workbook while doing it so I'm assuming you want to always have that formatting over those cells in the same workbook - in which case you might as well add it manually as it only needs doing once.  If you're creating a new workbook/new sheets as part of the process then VBA may be the way to go, or it might be easier to have a template sheet that you copy. It all depends... your code is all we've go to on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for complicated VBA solution for something as simple as Conditional formatting

Just select column you want to highlight when there is error and create new conditional formatting as follow

```
=$B1=" //your condition "
```

"$" lock just columns ( or row if before numbers ) you want to lock just one side

So if you want highlight column B if somewhere in that column is written error you put there this

```
=$B1="error"
```

simple hope i helped and sorry for bad English

Comment: Hi, your conditional formatting works. However, I am trying to automate this highlighting. If I use VBA script, i can just insert the script and automate it easily.